# How can I make GPSMid work on evry mobile regardless preinstallation of Java (J2ME) application?

Tags: java

I am trying to make GPSMid Work on every mobile but the problem is they all depend on the pre-installation of J2ME (Java) application.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to run a Java application, you need to have a JVM running. If you do not have a JVM, then, the application will simply (to my knowledge) not run. On the other hand, many mobile phone brands have Java support out of the box, so basically your application will run without the need of having to install something before hand. The only exception that comes to mind is the iPhone, since it does not support Java, you will have to write your application in Objective C.

Comment: Is there any site I can download an already compiled application in Objective C for iPhones or is it a must to write one on my own.

Comment: I do not think that there is such a site... however, I believe that there are converters available.